# Coding using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, attributes

I want to apply 2 or more style attributes to the text of my paragraph, such as font color and font type. I am using CSS. When I use only one, such as: `p {color:green}` it's okay but when I apply more than one line of code, to the one paragraph, I have error code.

As you know we have 6 levels of heading such as h1 through h6, but if you want to write three attributes for the one heading? How do you do it?
Below I apply one attribute for body, one for heading(h1) and one for paragraph (p).

```
BODY {BACKGRUND-COLOR:LIGHTGRAY}
h1   {COLOR:BLUE}
p    {COLOR:GREEN}
```

Comment: Best to go to http://www.w3schools.com/css/ and start trying things out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this?

```
BODY {BACKGRUND-COLOR:LIGHTGRAY}
h1   {
      color: #444; 
      font-weight:bold;
      text-align:left;
}

p {COLOR:GREEN}
```

Just expand the { .. } brackets, and then add attributes separated by semicolons